# quick release clamps for fixing a standing desk to wall

Tags: furniture, construction

I just installed an IKEA SKARSTA. In the top position it wobbles a lot when I type, sufficiently to be annoying to unusable. My quick solution was to add 1 bracket at each end and screw them on to the wall.

But now I have a standing desk that's no longer adjustable. I was thinking of some kind of hold down clams that I could lock/unlock when the desk is up (it will have 2 positions). Something like:

[image: clamps]

Simple schematic, top view

[image: how the clam should track]

Can anyone suggest a type of clamp that would work in this case ? The goal would be to force the desk against the wall.

PS: The wobble comes from the extending mechanism, there is a lot of play between the fixed and mobile part of the extending legs, and I went to the IKEA and the show room model has the same issue. There is no fixing it.

Comment: The offset type toggle latches that you show are designed to be used inline not an an angle as you show in the other picture.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I know that, I'm looking for the correct variant

Comment: I guess in my comment was really aimed at asking if you could just place the pictured toggle latch on the bottom side of your work surface and have it pull the desk straight back to the wall.

Comment: the desk very close to the wall, but I guess I can put a 2 cm strip between the wall and it and use that as anchor. I'm not sure it would be sturdy enough. I will keep it as a backup solution. Thanks. To clarify: I can't find any anchors for this type of clamp that could sit at 90deg fixed tot the wall, it seems that they need to sit on the same surface, that's why I'm thinking of a strip of wood fixed on the wall

Comment: I had a wobbly desk that simply jamming a superball in-between the desk and wall fixed.

Comment: A photo of the actual desk frame against the wall would help.